# Java: Why does my code automatically and infinitely loop when an exception is entered instead of waiting for new input?

Tags: java, exception, while-loop

I am trying to make a loop that prompts the user for a positive integer so it can be saved into int x.

If a negative or non-integer is entered it will prompt the user again.

It seems to work when a negative value is entered, but not when an exception is entered.

When an exception is entered it just endlessly prints "Please enter a positive integer." without allowing input.

What am I doing wrong? Please help guide me.

Thanks in advance.

```
int x = 0;

boolean firstLoop = false;
        
while (firstLoop == false)
{
    firstLoop = true;

    try
    {
        x = in.nextInt();
    }
            
    catch (InputMismatchException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer.");
        firstLoop = false;
    }
            
    if (x < 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer.");
        firstLoop = false;
    }    
}
```

Comment: You're probably just getting "InputMismatchException" exception again and again. You need to do something to clear the scanner? Is that what "in" is?

Comment: There's a second bug.  If the user types in `-1` he'll get reprompted as intended.  If he then types `X` he'll be reprompted twice.  The catch-clause should reset x to 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you type in an illegal character that can't be parsed to an int, you will get an `InputMismatchException`.  Since `firstloop` is set to false, the loop continues.  But the illegal character is still in the buffer so it continues to repeat.  So do something like `in.nextLine();` in the first catch block to  start over and clear the bad character including the newline.

Comment: Editorial: I've come to the conclusion that Scanner should simply not be taught to beginners; more often than not, they are not equipped with a mental picture of what is going on, particularly with respect to the notional input cursor.  This lack shows up in two ways: the confusion about why nextLine() yields an empty string after some nextInt() call or similar, and the present confusion about error recovery.

Comment: @user16632363 correct, Scanner is too circumstantial. Hundreds of questions only on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You miss `in.hasNextInt()/in.hasNextLine()/in.nextLine()`.

If you can do without console in the IDE, better use [`java.io.Console`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Console.html) instead
of Scanner on System.in.

You then need to convert yourself: `int Integer.parseInt(String)` but it is much cleaner, and allows better prompts.

```
Console con = System.console();
int x = 0;
for (;;) {
    String input = con.readLine("Please enter a positive integer <= %d: ",
            Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    if (input == null) { // User ended console.
        break;
    }
    if (input.matches("\\d+")) { // 1 or more digits.
        x = Integer.parseInt(input);
        break;
    } else {
        con.printf("This '%s' is not a positive integer.%n", input);
    }
}
```